Flutter Spotify OAuth
When I click Agree or Cancel on the Spotify OAuth Page (my app, Marketify, would like to connect to Spotify) nothing happens. The website does not redirect to my app.
class SpotifyService {
  late final SpotifyApi spotify;
  late String responseUri;
  StreamSubscription<String?>? linksStream;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const clientId = '***';
    final clientSecret = dotenv.env['CLIENT_SECRET'];
    if (clientSecret == null) {
      throw Exception('CLIENT_SECRET is null');
    }
    final credentials = SpotifyApiCredentials(clientId, clientSecret);
    final grant = SpotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(credentials);
    const redirectUri = 'marketify://spotify-login-callback';
    final scopes = [
      AuthorizationScope.user.readPrivate,
      AuthorizationScope.library.read ,
      AuthorizationScope.playlist.modifyPrivate,
      AuthorizationScope.listen.readTop,
    ];

    final authUri = grant.getAuthorizationUrl(
      Uri.parse(redirectUri),
      scopes: scopes,
    );

    final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
    logger.d('Initial link: $initialLink');
    final responseUriCompleter = Completer<String>();

    linksStream = linkStream.listen((String? link) {
      logger.d('Received link: $link');
      if (link != null && link.startsWith(redirectUri)) {
        responseUriCompleter.complete(link);
      }
    });

    if (await canLaunchUrl(authUri)) {
      await launchUrl(authUri);
    }

    responseUri = await responseUriCompleter.future;

    spotify = SpotifyApi.fromAuthCodeGrant(grant, responseUri);
    await linksStream?.cancel();


  }
}

I am trying to run the app on iOS currently. I tried adding the following lines to my info.plist file
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.example.marketify</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>marketify</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

I have confirmed that the callback uri on the Spotify developer board is the same as the one detailed in the app ('marketify://spotify-login-callback'). It is worth noting that the logger does not seem to receive any link at all.
I am using the Spotify dart package to access the Spotify API elsewhere in the app, and the uni_links package to (attempt to ) read the callback url.
Thanks for any advice.
